# Loading A HTML From Another Directory In Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, file, electron

I am trying to make an electron app and I need to load a HTML to a BrowserWindow but the script that controls this is in another Directory which isn't the same as the HTML's ones.

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is my code to load the HTML into the BrowserWindow:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const {BrowserWindow} = electron;
//This part is called from an exported function
const window = new BrowserWindow();
window.setSize(500 , 500);
window.show();
window.setMenu(null);
window.loadFile("../HTML/MainWindow.html");
```

The window is created but it doesn't load the HTML into it which is really weird, someone help? By the way keep in mind that I don't create the window from the main script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this

```
var path = require('path');
window.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '../HTML/MainWindow.html'))
```

Comment: Okay! So it did work but I had to change your line to: window.loadURL(path.join(__dirname,  '../HTML/MainWindow.html'))

Comment: Right! I forgot to add the HTML to your path, I will update the answer. Can you mark it as answer?

Comment: Only worked when I changed `window.loadURL()` to `window.loadFile()`

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the problem by importing path like what @Luis Daniel Sandi talled me to do and then I just did: `window.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '../HTML/MainWindow.html'))` and instead of importing BrowserWindow from electron I imported that from `electron.remote`.